# How to remove default demand DotNetFramework from TFS agent?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I am using TFS 2017 and recently added RHEL Linux build agent with docker installed on it, but when I am trying to queue docker based build on this agent I am getting below error

```
Issues with deploy phase 'Run on agent' - No agents could be found that match the following demands (queue: 'DockerLinuxRHEL'): DotNetFramework
```

[image]

I have also tried removing it from build definition, but it's greyed out.

[image]

Is there a way to remove this default demand because this agent is just for docker stuff I don't want to install anything else?

Comment: Go to the build definition and remove the demand.

Comment: Thanks @ShaykiAbramczyk but it's greyed out, can't remove it.

Comment: Can you share your build definition?

Comment: you mean the steps by the way I have attached screenshot in the question.

Comment: yes, the steps.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I have 3 docker task and 1 powershell task. I got it when I have disabled powershell task demands automatically deleted.

Comment: Exactly what I thought, you had a task that requires dotnet :)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk but to use just 1 powershell task do I need to install dotnet framework.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216431/discussion-between-naveen-kumar-and-shayki-abramczyk).

Comment: Yes, PowerShell uses .net framework behind the scenes.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk but I think there is no .net framework for Linux right?

Comment: There is .net core and PowerShell core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It because you have a task that required .Net framework installed, like PowerShell, MSBuild, etc.

When you will remove the task the demand will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

> How to remove default demand DotNetFramework from TFS agent?

I am afraid we could not remove the default demand DotNetFramework.

Just like Shayki said the demand comes from the powershell task itself. So, if we want use the powershell task, we have to install the Net Framework on Linux machine.

However, it's **not recommended** to build `.net framework` projects in Linux environment.  Usually we use `mono` with reference assemblies and the `dotnet cli` to do that.

More details please refer to [this blog](https://andrewlock.net/building-net-framework-asp-net-core-apps-on-linux-using-mono-and-the-net-cli/) and the discussion [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/335).

So, remove default demand DotNetFramework or install Net Framework on Linux machine is not a viable option.

To resolve this issue, we could use the [PowerShell Core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops):

```
- pwsh:  # inline script
  workingDirectory:  #
  displayName:  #
  failOnStderr:  #
  errorActionPreference:  #
  ignoreLASTEXITCODE:  #
  env:  # mapping of environment variables to add
```

Note: `pwsh` runs PowerShell Core, which must be installed on the agent or container.

Hope this helps.